# Access process i18n property files before compilation

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a following situation: in some of my i18n property files there are properties containing a special word:

- prop.example=`specialword` just for example
- prop.test=just for test `specialword`

I want to have a possibility of having a property somewhere in my *Config.groovy* that would contain a specific value for this `specialword` so that if I specify:

```
specialword=Value of special word
```

in a *Config.groovy* then I want my i18n properties to be resolved like:

- prop.example=`Value of special word` just for example
- prop.test=just for test `Value of special word`

for that purpose, when building the project, I want to access property files in order to look for occurences of `specialword` and to replace them with value of `specialword`value from Config.groovy.

Is that possible somehow? Perhaps, someone faced similar situation? I would really appreciate any help. 
Thanks, Cheers

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to go about solving the root issue the wrong way. Why not pass the value as an argument to your property when you do message code resolution instead? That way you can define it in `Config.groovy` as a part of your application configuration like you want and not have to "hack" into the compile process? Seems like you are fighting against the system here ...

Comment: @JoshuaMoore but what happens if for, lets say, EN locale and specific label, I need this feature and I use argument for that, but for FR locale and the same label I don't need this special word and hence don't use argument, wouldn't in end up with exception if I try to pass an argument there?

Comment: No, the argument will be ignored if it's not used in the message code.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks so much Joshua! You've been saving my life many times since I started working with grails, thank you

Comment: No worries, happy to help. I appreciate the thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the way the properties are compiled, you would be better off passing the special value as an argument to your message code (as discussed in the comments to your question).

For instance:
`<g:message code="my.key.code" args="[someVariableWithAValueFromConfig]" />`

If your message code doesn't use the argument it will simply be ignored. This seems like the best approach to the problem you are trying to solve.